# How to define multivariable vector funtion?

Tags: vector, variable-definitions

I would like to define a function of variables having two components as $u(x,y) = (f(x,y),g(x,y))$. I defined such a function as

```
u[x_, y_] := {f[x, y], g[x, y]}
```

without any error message. Now when I want to take a dot product of this vector with another vector $v = (1,5)$ following result is obtained,

```
v = {1,5}

u[x, y].v
u[x, y].v
```

with last line being output. How is possible to answer as $u[x, y]\cdot v = ({f[x, y], g[x, y]})\cdot (1,5) =  f(x,y) +5g(x,y)$ ?

Comment: When I run this, I get exactly what you expected.  Maybe restart the kernel and try again?

Comment: me too the code is just fine restart kernel !

Comment: you can't have + since you put , in your definition !
=(,)+5(,)  cant be.
Replace , with + if needed
u[x_, y_] := {f[x, y] + g[x, y]}

Comment: thanks a lot @ChrisK, I get the correct result with  a restart. Very surprised since I had $ClearAll["Global`*"]$ at the top :)

Comment: Here you go check answer part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the exact expression you showed, i.e. to "show the steps"?

Perhaps you could use Inactivate to get something similar:

```
Defer[u[x, y].v] == Inactivate[u[x, y].v, Dot] == u[x, y].v
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could get the answer with simply $u[x, y].v$. What is the advantage of using Inactivate?

Comment: @alekhine I thought that you wanted to obtain the whole chain of transformations shown in your $LaTeX$ expression, i.e. the "steps" to get to the answer. There is no advantage to using `Inactivate` etc if you just want the result :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Trace` works on the given problem (judging by the currently accepted answer by @MarcoB):

```
Equal @@ Trace[
  u[x, y].v,
  TraceDepth -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or:

```
Equal @@ Trace[
  u[x, y].v,
  TraceDepth -> 1,
  TraceOriginal -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]